# Generalization of sum of angles to polyhedra?

Tags: geometry, polyhedra

The sum of interior angles of a polygon is (n-2)*180. Is there a similar statement for the sum of the solid angles of a polyhedra?
Is there any non-trivial relationship, $f(\alpha,\beta,...)=0$, between the solid angles at all? If not, can we prove it?

If not, is there another generalization of this formula for polyhedra or higher dimensions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a beautiful formula for $d$-dimensional convex polytopes $P$, called *Brianchon-Euler-Gram theorem* (see for instance Theorem 22 [here](http://home.engineering.iastate.edu/~namrata/CSclass/convex_polytopes.pdf))  which generalizes the classical formula for the angle sum of polygons:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^d (-1)^i \sum_{F, \ dim(F)=i}\angle_F(P)=0. 
$$
Here $\angle_F(P)$ is the solid angle of $P$ at the face $F$ (of dimension $i$). In order to understand this formula, let's consider the case $d=2$. Then $P$ will have faces of dimension $0$ (vertices), dimension $1$ (edges) and dimension $2$ (the single facet, $P$ itself). If $F$ is an edge, then $\angle(F)=\pi$, if $F=P$ then $\angle(F)=2\pi$, while at the vertices we get the usual angles. 
(In order to understand this, you note that $\angle(F)$ is defined by picking a generic point $x\in F$ and computing the total solid angle occupied by $P$ in the small sphere centered at $x$.) If $P$ has $n$ vertices (and, hence, edges), the B-E-G formula then reads
$$
(\sum_{v\in Vert(P)} \angle_v(P) )- n\pi  + 2\pi=0,
$$
i.e.,
$$
\sum_{v\in Vert(P)} \angle_v(P)= (n-2)\pi. 
$$
If you want to see some identities involving only solid angles at the vertices, consider reading for instance the paper

["Generalized Solid Angle Theory for Real
Polytopes"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0708.0042.pdf), by DeSario and Robbins,

and papers cited there, although, personally, I find this staff impenetrable.

Answer (score 1):

The sum of the *solid* angles of polyhedradoes not follow such a simple law. For example, the eight solid angles of a cube add up to one full angle, i.e.  $4\pi$ sr, but for a very flat quadratic frustrum the sum is approximately twice as much.

Comment: Ok, but this doesnt preclude some slightly more complex law